# How do I retrieve the return value from a stored function call in groovy?

Tags: oracle, groovy

I am trying to make a call to a stored function in Oracle.  This function not only has a return value but also has an OUT parameter.  I am relatively new to Groovy but have a lot of database experience.  How do I retrieve the actual values returned.  Here is my sample call...assume I already have a good database connection.

I have a store function with the following signature:

```
GET_JOB(job_id IN VARCHAR2, max_sal OUT INTEGER) RETURNS VARCHAR2
```

I make the call in groovy:

```
def result = sql.call("{? = call get_job(?, ?)}", [Sql.VARCHAR, 'TE', Sql.NUMERIC])
```

This seems to run with no errors, but I am unclear as to how to retrieve the return value and the OUT parameter (second parameter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `int Sql.call(String, List)` form of the method doesn't handle output parameters. You can use `void Sql.call(String, List, Closure)` instead.

```
sql.call("{? = call get_job(?, ?)}", [Sql.VARCHAR, 'TE', Sql.NUMERIC]) { maxSal ->

    // do whatever with maxSal
}
```

Note: If you get the return value of the stored procedure instead of the out parameter, try: `sql.call(...) { ret, maxSal -> }`

Comment: Looks like I needed to put two values in the closure: sql.call("""{? = call get_job(?, ?)}""", [Sql.VARCHAR, 'TE', Sql.NUMERIC]) { retVal, row ->
   println row
   println retVal
}